# Best practice for loading fragment (Loading part)

Tags: android

I want to make a smooth transaction between fragments when chosen from the NavigationDrawer. Many of the fragments are rather heavy with its own sub-fragments etc and will cause stutter if just loaded like normal from the main activity/navigation drawer.

What is the best practice here? Right now I'm thinking of creating a "LoadingActiviy" with a transparent background and progressbar inside it. Starting it before fragment is called and finish() it from within the fragment when its finished with all its stuff. So: Create, destroy, create, destroy for every change of page.

Is this a good way of doing it? Feels wrong somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

Comment: I dont see the relation? (Except for the title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is a workaround, not a solution! You're saying that your fragments are heavy so make it not heavy! If fragment takes long to load it usually means that you do a lot of work on the main thread, by offloading your work to other threads your fragment can start right away and show a progress bar if necessary until the job is done.